# XSLT: How to copy elements from parent node and delete them afterwards

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<entry>
<form type="variant">
    <form type="hyperlemma">
        <orth>wordA</orth>
    </form>
    <orth>wordB</orth>
    <gramGrp>
        <gram>vb</gram>
        <gram>inf</gram>
    </gramGrp>
    <cit>
        <form type="lemma">
            <orth>wordC</orth>
        </form>
    </cit>
    <form type="graphical_variant">
        <form type="hyperlemma">
            <orth>wordD</orth>
        </form>
        <orth>wordE</orth>
        <cit>
            <orth>∅</orth>
        </cit>
    </form> 
</form>
</entry>
```

Child nodes of `<form type="variant">` - namely `<orth>wordB</orth>` and `<cit>` - are supposed to go in a second `<form type="graphical_variant">` that is newly added right before the first one.

The desired output is

```
<entry>
<form type="variant">
    <form type="hyperlemma">
        <orth>wordA</orth>
    </form>
    <gramGrp>
        <gram>vb</gram>
        <gram>inf</gram>
    </gramGrp>
    <form type="graphical_variant">
        <orth>wordB</orth>
        <cit>
        <form type="lemma">
            <orth>wordC</orth>
        </form>
    </cit>
    </form>
    <form type="graphical_variant">
        <form type="hyperlemma">
            <orth>wordD</orth>
        </form>
        <orth>wordE</orth>
        <cit>
            <orth>∅</orth>
        </cit>
    </form> 
</form>
</entry>
```

Applying this XSLT, templates 1 and 2 are doing the copying

```
<!--TEMPLATE1-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!--TEMPLATE2-->
<xsl:template match="form[@type='graphical_variant']">
    <form type="graphical_variant">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../orth" />
        <!--in case there are several <cit> elements-->
        <xsl:for-each select="../cit">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </form>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!--TEMPLATE3-->
<xsl:template match="form[@type='variant']/cit" />
<!--TEMPLATE4-->
<xsl:template match="form[@type='variant']/orth"/>
```

But as soon as I try to delete those copied elements from `<form type="variant">` using templates 3 and 4, they are deleted from the newly created element `<form type="graphical_variant">`, too.

This may be a stupid question, but why is that so? By referring to `form[@type='variant']` (template3), I thought `<cit>` was going to be deleted there only. I'd be glad if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong - and perhaps even provide a solution!

I forgot to mention: it is XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that when you do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../orth" />
```

you are applying templates to `orth` elements that are siblings of the current node - i.e. children of the `<form type="variant">` element. There's only template that matches these `orth` elements - it's your TEMPLATE4, and that template is empty.

Same thing happens with your:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../cit">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

That's just an awkward way of saying:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../cit" />
```

which applies the empty TEMPLATE3 to these nodes.

**How to fix this:**

There are three ways you could approach this:

1. Instead of applying templates, **copy** the nodes to where you want
       them:

   ```
   <!--TEMPLATE1--> 
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template>
   <!--TEMPLATE2--> 
   <xsl:template match="form[@type='graphical_variant']">
       <form type="graphical_variant">
           <xsl:copy-of select="../orth" />
           <xsl:copy-of select="../cit" />
       </form>
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template>
   <!--TEMPLATE3--> 
   <xsl:template match="form[@type='variant']/cit" />
   <!--TEMPLATE4--> 
   <xsl:template match="form[@type='variant']/orth"/>
   ```
2. Apply different templates (using *mode*) when you want the nodes to be copied.
3. Be more selective when applying the templates (this, IMHO, is the
   preferable approach):

   **XSLT 2.0**

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="form[@type='variant']">
       <xsl:copy>
           <!-- remove orth and cit from here -->
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except (orth|cit)"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="form[@type='graphical_variant']">
       <form type="graphical_variant">
           <!-- add orth and cit here -->
           <xsl:apply-templates select="../orth" />
           <xsl:apply-templates select="../cit" />
       </form>
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I opted for approach 3, which (even to me) seems the most elegant. And I wasn't aware of the "except" feature. This is definitely useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." />
```

Here you go, it matches to empty templates towards the bottom of your example.

Simple, however not optimal solution would be

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="noignore" />
```

And then make 's that match your desired elements with mode="noignore" and actually copy them instead of suppressing.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you made! Unfortunately, I was not able to make your suggestion work as you did not elaborate where exactly to place it.